# MySQL stored procedure with variable argument list

Tags: mysql

I have made a stored procedure. I want it to filter the data by different parameters. If I pass one parameter, it should be filtered by one; if I pass two, it should be filtered by two, and so on, but it is not working.

Can anyone help me please?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS medatabase.SP_rptProvince2;
CREATE PROCEDURE medatabase.`SP_rptProvince2`(
 IN e_Region VARCHAR(45)
  )
BEGIN

 DECLARE strQuery VARCHAR(1024);
 DECLARE stmtp   VARCHAR(1024);
  SET @strQuery = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM alldata where 1=1');
  IF e_region IS NOT NULL THEN
   SET @strQuery = CONCAT(@strQuery, ' AND (regionName)'=e_Region);
  END IF;

 PREPARE  stmtp FROM  @strQuery;
 EXECUTE  stmtp;
END;
```

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK, you can't have a variable argument list like that.  You can do one of a couple of things:

1. Take a fixed maximum number of parameters, and check them for null-ness before concatenating:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE SP_rptProvince2(a1 VARCHAR(45), a2 VARCHAR(45), ...)

   ...

     IF a1 IS NOT NULL THEN
       SET @strQuery = CONCAT(@strQuery, ' AND ', a2);
     END IF;
   ```

   If you need predetermined fields to which the criteria in the argument apply (like the `e_Region` parameter in your existing code), then you modify the CONCAT operation appropriately.

   Possible invocation:

   ```
   CALL SP_rptProvince2('''North''', 'column3 = ''South''')
   ```
2. Take a single parameter that is much bigger than just 45 characters, and simply append it to the query (assuming it is not null).

   Clearly, this places the onus on the user to provide the correct SQL code.

   Possible invocation:

   ```
   CALL SP_rptProvince2('RegionName = ''North'' AND column3 = ''South''')
   ```

There's not a lot to choose between the two.  Either can be made to work; neither is entirely satisfactory.

You might note that there was a need to protect the strings in the arguments with extra quotes; that is the sort of thing that makes this problematic.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. but give me this error Lookup error-Mysql Database Error:unknown column 'South' in 'where clause'

Comment: You are expected to think for yourself.  I don't know from your comment where 'South' came from; I don't know from your question which column your second or subsequent arguments should be associated with; I can't tell how you want to call it.  You have to fill in that sort of detail and *think* for yourself.

Comment: i m using this procedure for reporting i have 5 parameters in this procedure if i don't pass a parameter all data should be dispalyed if i pass one parameter the view should be filtered on base of one and the other four parameters will be passed null if i passed two parameters the view should be filtered by two parameters and the other three parameters will be passed null and so on this is the concept of the procedure. if you could help me that will be highly appreciated i m new to mysql i did the same in sqlserver 2005 and it is working there but not working here in mysql.

Comment: Your question more or less shows how to deal with one possibly null parameter; we can debate the exact syntax in the CONCAT (it should probably be more like `CONCAT(@strQuery, ' AND regionName = ', eRegion)`, though that relies on the user to enter a string such as `'''South'''` as the argument).  Ensuring that quotes are properly handled is modestly tough but very important to avoid [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327).  Extending that idea from one to five parameters is a trivial application of the same idea, repeated several times.

Comment: `IF a1 IS NOT NULL THEN SET @strQuery = CONCAT(@strQuery, ' AND ', a2);` - I am a complete SQL ignorant but would you mean `' AND ', a1);`

Comment: Possibly — or `IF a2 IS NOT NULL THEN ... ' AND ', a2);`.  Either way, you're correct that I've got a mismatch between the tested variable and the appended variable.

Answer (score 4):

I found a JSON-based approach which works with the latest MySQL/MariaDB systems. Check the link below (Original Author is Federico Razzoli): https://federico-razzoli.com/variable-number-of-parameters-and-optional-parameters-in-mysql-mariadb-procedures

Basically, you take a BLOB parameter which is actually a JSON object and then do ***JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json object, key))*** as appropriate.

Lifted an extract here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION table_exists(params BLOB)
    RETURNS BOOL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    COMMENT '
Return whether a table exists.
Parameters must be passed in a JSON document:
* schema (optional). : Schema that could contain the table.
                       By default, the schema containing this procedure.
* table              : Name of the table to check.
'
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_table VARCHAR(64)
        DEFAULT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(params, '$.table'));
    DECLARE v_schema VARCHAR(64)
        DEFAULT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(params, '$.schema'));

    IF v_schema IS NULL THEN
        RETURN EXISTS (
            SELECT TABLE_NAME
                FROM information_schema.TABLES
                WHERE
                    TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
                    AND TABLE_NAME = v_table
        );
    ELSE
        RETURN EXISTS (
            SELECT TABLE_NAME
                FROM information_schema.TABLES
                WHERE
                    TABLE_SCHEMA = v_schema
                    AND TABLE_NAME = v_table
        );
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Love this answer. Except params should be a varchar. Using blob as the type for the input `params` gave me the following error in 5.7: `ERROR 3144 (22032): Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.`.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

You can insert the variable number of parameters in a temporary table in the session, before you call the stored procedure, one parameter in each row. Then the stored procedure can read the rows of that temp table and take actions according to the number of parameters passed in the rows of the temporary table.