# Passing numbers array to stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to pass an array of numbers to a stored procedure for use with IN operator?
I have something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (1,2,3);
```

And I want to pass `(1,2,3)` as an argument. Is this possible?

Comment: There are answers covering this topic in most any programming language. What language are you using?

Comment: But I ask about SQL. I want to define stored procedure and call it via parameterised query. And it seems there's no way in mysql to pass this so-called array for IN operator...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
  create procedure test (@input1 integer(2) in,@input2 integer(2) in,@input3 integer(2) in)
  as 
  select * from table where col in (@input1,@input2,@input3);
```

Comment: Abu, the problem is that my 'array' length vary from query to query.

Comment: Have a look at this one it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369574/mysql-stored-procedure-with-variable-argument-list

Comment: So you kinda say that what I want is not possible at all. Well, if I find no other solution I'll mark your answer...