# Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE expected 1, got 2

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Equipment(IN id int(11))
    BEGIN
SELECT  * FROM  equip a,    Txn_code b
WHERE   a.id = b.id AND a.id in(id);
    END //
DELIMITER 


call equipment(1000001109,1000001040)
```

If I call the Above Procedure,I get an error...Please help me out

Error 1318  Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE; expected 1, got 2

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure only defines one argument "id".

So you need to call it with just one argument --> `call equipment(1000001109)`

That will fix calling your procedure,... but then your SELECT isn't going to do what you want.

Please refer to this similar question which discusses the issue of variable number of arguments in stored procedures calls (the solution is non-trivial AFAIK):

[MySQL Stored Procedure with variable argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369574/mysql-stored-procedure-with-variable-argument-list)

Comment: HI I know that my procedure only defines one argument "id"  when i call equipment(1000001109) its working.
I have a table equipment it has more than 10,000 records..I want to see the selected 4 or 5 records from that table,
For that i dont want to write select query for that, So i need Procedure to reduce my time cost...

Answer (score 1):

you try to send 2 parameters to the procedure, but in the declaration she get only one